# Possible bug in Developer Story - Job match preferences is being ignored

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story, email

I am using Developer Story with preference "Actively looking right now" and in the "[Board](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current#job-board)" in option "Send Stack Overflow Jobs emails to" I have a different email from my current login account.

Instead of receiving email to the address inserted in "Send Stack Overflow Jobs emails to" I receive emails from potential employers to my current login account address (they are different).

For privacy reasons, I would like to have all job related emails to that specific email inputted in the Job setting and not the current login account.

- Is this a bug? Or my wrong settings?

Notes: I have notice that "Q&A Emails" is the same of the current login account.

Comment: Are you getting these emails as response to your applications? or from employers that find your profile? Are these emails sent using our messaging system? I'm seeing only one email in your account. Can you send me those 2 addresses via email? my address is on my profile

Comment: @g3rv4 - NO, YES, NO, It seems that the employer is able to see email for my “current login account” instead of "Send Stack Overflow Jobs emails to” only. Which email are employers suppose to see? How to shoe the employer only "Send Stack Overflow Jobs emails to”? Thanks for your support.

Comment: @g3rv4 can the employer see email in "Q&A Emails" preference?

Comment: If you have an email defined for Jobs, then that's the email the employer should see. However, when looking into your account information, I see the same address (its md5 hash ends with a4593b0) everywhere (Q&A, Jobs, account). I also see one employer mentioned something like "I'll write you to x@y.com", that's why I'm having a hard time understanding the issue. Can you shoot me an email with a screenshot of your preferences tab showing the different email addresses? from what I see on our db, all the communications (Q&A and Jobs) should be sent to that address

Comment: @g3rv4
Correct, I noticed this issue when the employer mention my email in that comunication.
I placed back my email as before in order to help you to reproduce the error:
You can find email at:
Edit Profile & Settings / SITE SETTINGS: Preferences / Q&A Emails: Send notification emails to 

Now email address in "Q&A Email" and “Jobs Emails” are different, are you able to reproduce the error?

Comment: @g3rv4 just an idea... you can try to login as "employer" and see if you can see "Q&A Emails" or  one of email from "current login account"? Please let me know thanks!

Comment: I still see the same email address everywhere... did you update it and save? employers only see your email address if you apply to a position or if you reply to a message saying that you're interested, that's why just searching for you in the employer console won't let me see your email. Still, I'm checking directly on the database and I still see that email everywhere.

Comment: @g3rv4  Yes was saved and updated, I sent you an email with screenshot of what I see in my account. Please let me know thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL:DR:** Fixed.

The issue was related to the fact that you updated your email address after an employer initially messaged you.

Even though messages sent from the messaging UI were sent to the updated email address, the email address *displayed in the UI* was the old one. The employer could copy-paste this old email address and message you from an external email client. This appears to be what happened.

The displayed email address is now the most up-to-date one.

Please note that this issue only affected conversations which were started before you updated your email address.

Thanks for your report!